# .Net only 1 of several embedded DLL's not loading

Tags: .net, vb.net, dllimport

I'm using the following code to load an embedded DLL resource (cut down code for brevity):

```
Dim ba() As Byte = Nothing
Dim asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = Nothing
Dim curAsm As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Using stm As Stream = curAsm.GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedResource)
    ba = New Byte(CInt(stm.Length) - 1) {}
    stm.Read(ba, 0, CInt(stm.Length))
    Try
        asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(ba)
        dic.Add(asm.FullName, asm)
        If verbose Then MsgBox("Loaded direct from embedded resources OK: " & fileName)
        Return
    Catch e As Exception
    If verbose Then MsgBox(fileName & " - Error: " & e.Message)

    ' Purposely do nothing
    ' Unmanaged dll or assembly cannot be loaded directly from byte[]
    ' Let the process fall through for next part
    End Try
End Using
```

The program JIT errors whenever the last THREE of the following embedded DLL's are accessed!
The resource code copies out the DLL into the folder if it's unmanaged, or can't be loaded from byte[] as it says above... I've traced the following being loaded, ALL of them get registered with System.Reflection.Assembly.Load - none needed to get copied to the folder for loading the normal way.

```
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll", "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll", "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll")
EmbeddedAssembly.preLoad("DatabaseRestore.Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll", "Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll")
```

Despite this, 3 DLL's: Zip.Reduce, as well as WindowsAPICodePack and WindowsAPICodePack.Shell cause the following JIT error to appear...

I don't understand WHY those last three DLL's are reported as missing when the program is running, when they've been loaded successfully?
The JIT error gives the exact DLL version I've embedded!

I don't know what to try to diagnose the problem either.

(Luckily the program works with those 3 DLL's just in the program folder, but I want to understand why I can't embed them.)

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at DatabaseRestore.RestoreEngine.restore(RestoreInformation restoreDetails)
   at DatabaseRestore.FileBrowser.button_restore_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1086.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
DatabaseRestore
    Assembly Version: 1.0.9.6
    Win32 Version: 1.0.9.6
    CodeBase: file:///C:/ProgramOther/DatabaseRestore/DatabaseRestore.exe
----------------------------------------
....More....
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.6000.34 ((KJ_SP3).140819-1214 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.6000.34 ((KJ_SP3).140819-1214 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.9.6
    CodeBase: file:///C:/ProgramOther/DatabaseRestore/DatabaseRestore.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.9.6
    CodeBase: file:///C:/ProgramOther/DatabaseRestore/DatabaseRestore.exe
----------------------------------------
Ionic.Zip.Reduced
    Assembly Version: 1.9.1.8
    Win32 Version: 1.0.9.6
    CodeBase: file:///C:/ProgramOther/DatabaseRestore/DatabaseRestore.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.GeneratedCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1064.2 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------    




{Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
    CodeBase: "file:///C:/AssetManager/Tools/DatabaseRestore/DatabaseRestore_VisualStudio/DatabaseRestore/bin/Debug/DatabaseRestore.exe"
    CustomAttributes: Count = 17
    DefinedTypes: {Length=100}
    EntryPoint: Nothing
    EscapedCodeBase: "file:///C:/AssetManager/Tools/DatabaseRestore/DatabaseRestore_VisualStudio/DatabaseRestore/bin/Debug/DatabaseRestore.exe"
    Evidence: {System.Security.Policy.Evidence}
    ExportedTypes: {Length=51}
    FullName: "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    GlobalAssemblyCache: False
    HostContext: 0
    ImageRuntimeVersion: "v2.0.50727"
    IsDynamic: False
    IsFullyTrusted: True
    Location: ""
    ManifestModule: {Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll}
    Modules: {Length=1}
    PermissionSet:
    ReflectionOnly: False
    SecurityRuleSet: Level1 {1}
```

Comment: It sends chills up my spine when I see programmers do this.  But sure, this just can't work.  One rock-hard restriction in Assembly.Load(byte[]) is that it can only work on pure .NET assemblies.  Nothing pure about those three, they are mixed-mode assemblies that contain native machine code.  The OS loader requires them to be on a disk so it can map the code into memory with a memory-mapped file.  Rock-hard.

Comment: @HansPassant I see! So Load isn't failing even though they're mixed-mode... the loader function is supposed to catch an exception of that, and save the DLL's to the folder... When you mention a chilled spine - what's your thoughts? I did it originally when I was passing around EXE's in work, so that multiple files didn't need to be copied - just to make things a little tidier.

Comment: This doesn't go wrong until later, when the managed wrapper tries to call the native code.  You cannot know when that happens nor is it your code so you can't put try/catch around it.  But you know that it *will* happen, so might as well stay ahead of it and ensure the file is present.  Next thing that goes wrong is that you can't write where you prefer to write it.  Next thing that goes wrong is tickling anti-malware by making executable files appear from seemingly no-where.  Next thing that goes wrong is running out of memory a lot sooner by doubling the required address space.

Comment: @HansPassant I see, thank you.